# Cant get the values from materializecss MultiSelect

Tags: javascript, materialize

I would like to read the values ​​with js from a multiselect.
in the documentation of materializecss one should use `.getSelectedValues ​​()`.

The console tells me now that the function is not working.
I hope you can continue helping me there.

```
const selector = document.querySelectorAll('.funcselect');
const instanceSelector = M.FormSelect.init(selector);

function submitform() {
    // some other form to variables stuff

    var funcs = instanceSelector.getSelectedValues();

    // some xrh stuff

}
```

This is as basic as the code is constructed.

and here the console log:

```
js.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: instanceSelector.getSelectedValues is not a function
```

I hope someone can help me.

The documentation of the selector: https://materializecss.com/select.html

Comment: please add whole code or use jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wsvjnq5c/11/ its based on php so i had to change the options. and i changed the target url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `onChange` event to handle the changes of your `select`.

```
<div class="container row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select multiple>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var elems = document.querySelector('select');
        elems.onchange = selectThem;
        var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
        function selectThem() {
            var selectedOne = instances.getSelectedValues();
            console.log(selectedOne);
        }
    });
</script>
```

[change event - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

[Select - Materialize](https://materializecss.com/select.html)

Comment: Check `onchange` docs for better understanding of why I used `onchange` event for this.

Comment: How do you access the selectedOne outside the addEventListener? I tried your approach but it only returns the first option no matter what I selcted. getSelectedValues() function also not working for me either.